# tramp: permission denied when connecting with ssh

Tags: tramp

tramp:
I am using the command:
/ssh:ec2-user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/home/owner/.ssh/handson.pem

I get permission denied. puplickey, wssapi-keyex, gssapi-with-mic

ssh in the shell works

I tried this solution, but it did not help.

Comment: Check your shell config files and environment variables for related settings that you don't have inside Emacs.  If you're not starting Emacs *from a shell*, then test that as well.

Comment: I don't know, what to change.

Comment: I don't know either.  Start with the second suggestion though -- start Emacs from your shell and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Also, you've added "I tried this solution" with no context at all.  What did you try?

Comment: According to the error message, passwords are not checked. So there might be a dialogue with the ssh server is not aware of.

Pls show from the shell, how the ssh access works. Perhaps you can use "ssh -v ..." in order to get more information about the dialogue.

Pls be careful not to distribute secret information.

Comment: Which Emacs are you using? version 27, 28, or 29? For Windows or GNU/Linux? You may need to provide more information so that volunteers here can answer your question more easily  :-)